# why can't I access this method via inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have two simple classes, and wish to access the public method `stuff` by passing an `int` value. why can't I do that with an instance of Bar? Shouldn't it inherit the public method stuff. The type hinting gives the `int a` parameter, but it doesn't compile.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int a;
    void stuff(int a){ std::cout << a << std::endl; }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
protected:
    void stuff() { std::cout << "hello world"; }
};



void main()
{
    Bar b
    b.stuff(3);
}
```

Comment: try `b.Foo::stuff(3);`. You have to resolve explicitly the scope when calling the base class member function since the protected member function of the derived class hides it because they have the same name.

Comment: that did the trick, thanks. Does this mean that all inherited objects carry about a hidden member of their base class and members/methods of which have to be accessed via #a cross between instance and static method calls?

Comment: @RaymondChen no casting is occurring.

Comment: I wouldn't say that they carry hidden members of their base class but rather an object of their base class.

Comment: That's funky, but kinda makes sense - thanks!

Comment: You need to cast to make the method visible.

Comment: He doesn't refer to classical casting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `Bar::stuff` hides `Foo::stuff` (only the name matters when overload resolution is performed, parameters are ignored).

**You can :**

- Bring it into sope with a `using` declaration
- Or alternatively,  explicitly qualify the call e.g. `b.Foo::stuff(3);`.

**Note** :

- `main()` must return an `int`.

---

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    int a;
    void stuff(int a){ std::cout << a << std::endl; }
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    using Foo::stuff;
protected:
    void stuff() { std::cout << "hello world"; }
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    b.stuff(3);
}
```

Or :

```
int main()
{
    Bar b;
    b.Foo::stuff(3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this wraps everything up nicely. why must `main` return an int? Is it bad form in c++11 to declare main as void?

Comment: It is not  related to c++11, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 4):

In C++, name hiding can take place when one function in base class has the same name as one function in derived class.

**Phases of the function call process**

1. Name lookup
2. Overload resolution
3. Access control

Name lookup stops looking for other names as soon as it finds a name in derived class `Bar`. Therefore, `Bar::stuff()` hides any function with name `stuff` in `Foo`.

After the name lookup process,

- overload resolution fails since there is no `stuff(int)` in `Bar`.
- even though `stuff()` without `int` parameter is called, access control fails since `stuff()` is protected.

Answer (score 4):

When looking up the name `stuff`, the one in `Bar` found first. Once that is found, the access privileges are checked. Since `Bar::stuff` is protected, you are not able to use it from `main`.

From the draft standard:

> **10.2 Member name lookup [class.member.lookup]**
>
> 1 Member name lookup determines the meaning of a name (*id-expression*) in a class scope (3.3.7). Name lookup can result in an *ambiguity*, in which case the program is ill-formed. For an *id-expression*, name lookup begins in the class scope of `this`; for a *qualified-id*, name lookup begins in the scope of the *nestedname-specifier*. Name lookup takes place before access control (3.4, Clause 11).

Comment: I thought the whole point of using access modifiers like public/protected/private was to set the visibility so that the `stuff` in Bar isn't found?

Comment: @user3791372: The point is to set the visibility so that the `stuff` in `Bar` can't be _used_.

Answer (score 0):

```
b.Foo::stuff(3);
```

Or, you can do a trick to access any protected:)

```
void main()
{
    Bar b;
    class BarAccess : public Bar { friend void main(); }
    BarAccess * ba = reinterpret_cast<BarAccess *>(&b);
    ba->stuff(3);
    ba->stuff();
}
```

Comment: that's some 'trick' ;)

Comment: No offence, but I don't agree with this trick. You discard the meaning of encapsulation doing this.